# How To Get Length of String in ZSH From Function Output

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, zsh

I'm trying to get the length of the string that is returned from a function in ZSH. The problem is that this function ALSO returns strings from other functions like so: `echo "$(function1) $(function2)"`, as seen at the end of `git_bubble()`. Here is the source code I mentioned:

```bash
bubblify () {
    # This is a helper function to build custom bubbles.
    #
    # ARGS      VALUES          DESC
    # ----      ------          ----
    # 1.        {0, 1, 2, 3}        0: build left side bubble: content█
    #                               1: build middle part: █content█
    #                               2: build right side bubble: █content
    #                               3: build custom colored whole bubble: content
    #
    # 2.        string              content to be displayed in partial bubble
    #
    # 3.        {'001', '073' ...}  foreground color (text color) as zsh-color-code
    #
    # 4.        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}     0: Default foreground color
    #                               1: Normal font
    #                               2: Bold font
    #                               3: Faint font
    #                               4: Italic font
    #
    # 5.        {'001', '073' ...}  background color (bubble segment color) as zsh-color-code
    #
    # 6.        {0, 1}              0: Default background color
    #                               1: Normal color

    if [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo -n "$(foreground $5 $6)$blub_left$(foreground $3 $4)$(background $5 $6)$2$reset_color"
        # echo -n "$4$blub_left$3$4$2$reset_color"
    elif [[ $1 -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo -n "$(foreground $3 $4)$(background $5 $6)$2$reset_color"
        # echo -n "$3$4$2$reset_color"
    elif [[ $1 -eq 2 ]]; then
        echo -n "$(foreground $3 $4)$(background $5 $6)$2$reset_color$(foreground $5 $6)$blub_right$reset_color"
        # echo -n "$3$4$2$reset_color$4$blub_right$reset_color"
    elif [[ $1 -eq 3 ]]; then
        echo -n "$(foreground $5 $6)$blub_left$(foreground $3 $4)$(background $5 $6)$2$reset_color$(foreground $5 $6)$blub_right$reset_color"
        # echo -n "$4$blub_left$3$4$2$reset_color$4$blub_right$reset_color"
    else
        echo -n 'bblfy_fail'
    fi
}
```

I know that `bubblify()` uses 2 other functions called `foreground()` and `background()`, but they just set the color of the foreground and background using escape sequences like
`echo -n "\033[3;38;5;${1}m"` and `echo "\033[48;5;${1}m"`.

The main purpose of `bubblify` is to just help make bubbles with info in them for the terminal. I currently use it with `git_bubble()`.

```bash
git_bubble () {
    # This parses 'git status -s' to retrieve all necessary information...I am new to this zsh scripting...mercy!
    local git_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null)

    if [[ -n $git_branch ]]; then
    
        # branch name with symbol, initialize symbols and git status output
        local git_info="$git_branch_symbol $git_branch"
        local git_symbols=""
        local git_status=$(git status -s 2> /dev/null | awk '{print substr($0,1,2)}')

        # used for coloring (and some for icons)
        local git_unmerged=$(grep -m1 -E -- 'U|DD|AA' <<< $git_status)
        local git_branch_stashed=$(git stash list | grep $git_branch)
        local git_unstaged=$(echo -n $git_status | awk '{print substr($0,2,1)}')

        # used for icons
        local git_not_clean=$git_status
        local git_modified=$(grep -m1 'M' <<< $git_status)
        local git_added=$(grep -m1 'A' <<< $git_status)
        local git_deleted=$(grep -m1 'D' <<< $git_status)
        local git_untracked=$(grep -m1 '??' <<< $git_status)
        local git_renamed=$(grep -m1 'R' <<< $git_status)
        local git_copied=$(grep -m1 'C' <<< $git_status)

        # coloring
        if [[ -n $git_unmerged ]]; then
            local git_color=$git_unmerged_color
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_unmerged_symbol"
        elif [[ -n $git_branch_stashed ]]; then
            local git_color=$git_stashed_color
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_stashed_symbol"
        elif [[ -n "${git_unstaged//[$' \t\r\n']}" && -n $git_not_clean ]]; then
            local git_color=$git_unstaged_color
        elif [[ -z "${git_unstaged//[$' \t\r\n']}" && -n $git_not_clean ]]; then
            local git_color=$git_staged_color
        else
            local git_color=$git_clean_color
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_clean_symbol"
        fi

        # icons
        if [[ -n $git_modified ]]; then
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_modified_symbol"
        fi
        if [[ -n $git_added ]]; then
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_added_symbol"
        fi
        if [[ -n $git_deleted ]]; then
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_deleted_symbol"
        fi
        if [[ -n $git_untracked ]]; then
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_untracked_symbol"
        fi
        if [[ -n $git_renamed ]]; then
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_renamed_symbol"
        fi
        if [[ -n $git_copied ]]; then
            git_symbols="$git_symbols$git_copied_symbol"
        fi
        
        echo -n "$(bubblify 0 "on " $bright_white $bold $bubble_color $normal)$(bubblify 1 "$git_info " $git_color $bold $bubble_color $normal)$(bubblify 2 " $git_symbols" $git_symbols_color $normal $git_color $normal)"
    fi
}
```

The git bubble that `git_bubble` produces look something like this:
[image]

So, the string returned is a result of a function returning a string from another function like:
`<string> <- git_bubble() <- bubblify()`

The problem is that when I go to get the length of this bubble using this code:

```bash
git_bubble_info=$(git_bubble)
git_bubble_size=${#git_bubble_info}

echo "Size is: $git_bubble_size"
```

All I get is a number like `127`, even though the bubble is roughly 13 characters in size, including spaces and symbols.
I've also tried other things I saw on other similar stackoverflow posts like:

```bash
git_bubble_info=$(git_bubble)
temp_pattern='%([BSUbfksu]|([FK]|){*})'
git_bubble_size=${#${(S%%)git_bubble_info//$~temp_pattern/}}

echo "Size is: $git_bubble_size"
```

```bash
git_bubble_info=$(git_bubble)
git_bubble_size=`expr "$git_bubble_info" : '.*'`

echo "Size is: $git_bubble_size"
```

And I got the same results (wrong size). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong??

Does anyone have any advice on how to get the length of a string that's being returned from a function that also returns from another function?

Comment: Perhaps you have to redesign your functions. First of all, a zsh function does not **return** anything. It can write to stdout and stderr, and you can catch this output into a variable and get the length of **this** variable. Another possible way to get back data to the caller, is that a function can assign something to a global variable, and the variable is read by the calling process. Of course this requires that the function is not executed in a child process of the caller.

Comment: @user1934428 It took me a little while to digest and understand what you were telling me. And I just wanted to say Thank You!! I just realized I could have a global variable keep track of the size of the `git_bubble` as it is made inside the function instead of trying to get the size from the function output (stdout). That should do the trick! Thank You!!

Comment: It may work, but be careful: Having a global variable means that you can not run the code which modifies the variable inside a child process. If this can not be guaranteed, the only other means to communicate information back to the caller is via file: The caller passes a file name to the child process (via an environment variable), the child writes to the file what needs to be passed back, and the caller then reads the file.